# c++: passing PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER as constructor parameter doesn't compile

Tags: c++, parameters, initialization, pthreads, mutex

From man page we know we initialize a pthread_mutex_t as below:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

But when I tried to wrap up pthread_mutex_t into a class and pass PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER as ctor parameter, it doesn't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
class PthreadMutex {
    pthread_mutex_t& _mutex;
public:
    PthreadMutex(pthread_mutex_t& mutex) : _mutex(mutex) {}//error
    ~PthreadMutex() {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    }
    void lock() { pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex); }
    pthread_mutex_t& get() { return _mutex; }
};
int main() {
    PthreadMutex mutex (PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER);//error
    return 0;
}
```

The error says:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'void*&' to an rvalue of type 'pthread_mutex_t' {aka 'void*'}     
     PthreadMutex mutex (PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER);

note:   initializing argument 1 of 'PthreadMutex::PthreadMutex(void*&)'
     PthreadMutex(pthread_mutex_t& mutex) : _mutex(mutex) {}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Guess this is time to switch to std::thread.

Comment: `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is not `pthread_mutex_t`.

Comment: It's an `int` that's been cast. When the preprocessor is done, `PthreadMutex mutex (PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER);` resolves to something like `PthreadMutex mutex ((pthread_mutex_t)-1);` To take a reference, you need to have a real `pthread_mutex_t` to refer to.

Comment: What is the intention behind this class anyway? You are storing a reference to a mutex. Where do you want to store the actual mutex? `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is meant to initialize that actual mutex.

Comment: Going to have to do this the hard way, `{ pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; PthreadMutex mutex (mut); }` or rethink `PthreadMutex`

Comment: But anyway, as indicated above, since C++11 just use [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) instead which has a proper C++ interface and comes with classes implementing locking as well, such as [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Comment: @user17732522 it is not trying to copy a mutex. It is taking a reference to an existing mutex, and applying RAII semantics to locking/unlocking that mutex

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, as a lock it might make sense, but then OP is not using the class correctly by trying to pass it a mutex initializer as constructor argument.